# Modify sharepoint view to group recursively (subgroup)

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, grouping

When creating a view and setting group by value some field, it groups only 1 level deep, like this

```
A
--A.1
--A.2
A.2
--A.2.1
--A.2.2
B
--B.1
```

However i would like to group it to make a tree, a hierarchy.

```
A
--A.1
--A.2
----A.2.1
----A.2.2
B
--B.1
```

A flawless solution would be if i could just make my custom views to view a recursively grouped items.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

It should look something like this:

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1958/ss20090703135209.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1958/ss20090703135209.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to build your own ListView Webpart. However, there is already a third party product that does this, the [Bamboo Solutions tree View WebPart](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-38-1-tree-view-web-part.aspx)

Comment: I`ll take a look at the trial.

Maybe it can go, but all I need is much more simple. I added screenshot for what i want.

Comment: It would be either your own webpart, or a very, very complex piece of XSL (recursion etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the data from maybe a content query web part and format it with your own XSLT.

XSL is not the easist to do this with as it has no "stack" structure for easily nesting a linear list.